# How can I rewrite python code to javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

The code in python is:

```python
def trimTree(tree):
    p=tree[1]
    if type(p) == type(""): return p
    else :
        return(trimTree(p[0]),trimTree(p[1]))
```

where tree is:

```
[
  13,
  [ 6, [ 3, [Object], [Object] ], [ 3, 'a' ] ],
  [ 7, [ 3, 'b' ], [ 4, [Object], [Object] ] ]
]
```

when I convert I got error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

What should I do?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the Javascript you've tried already? Nobody can really help you with what you've given so far.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what the faulty javascript code looks like ??? Sorry, my crystal ball is out for repair...

Comment: Oh and yes FWIW: this Python snippet is not only totally irrelevant (your problem is with javascript code, no one cares wether it was ported from something else), but also fugly and totally broken.

Comment: how you are passing 'tree' , that tree structure is not python supported format.

Answer (score 0):

With a proper data structure, which means any node has only a length of two elements, you get a list of values in breaths first order (the result is here a string).

```js
function trimTree(tree) {
    var p = tree[1];
    return typeof p === 'string'
        ? p
        : trimTree(p[0]) + trimTree(p[1]);
}

var data = [
        13,
        [
            [6,
                [
                    [3,
                        [
                            [1, 'X'],
                            [2, 'Y']
                        ]
                    ],
                    [3, 'a']
                ]
            ],
            [7,
                [
                    [3, 'b'],
                    [4,
                        [
                            [2, 'Z'],
                            [2, 'Q']
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];

console.log(trimTree(data));
```